# Calculating gravitational force with multiple planets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors

I have a question regarding the following problem:

Given the following system of planets (see image), calculate the total gravitational force acting on $m_3$.

($m_1 = 2 \cdot 10^{20}kg;$ $m_2 = 1 \cdot 10^{20}kg;$ $m_3 = 1 \cdot 10^{19}kg;$ $R_1 = 2 \cdot 10^{10}m;$ $R_2 = 1 \cdot 10^{10} m$)

[image]

My way of thinking on how to solve the problem was to find the position of the center of mass first, which in this case is $\vec{r}_{cm}=\frac{1}{3} \cdot 10^{10} m$, then calculate the distance from the center of mass to $m_3$ ($R = \sqrt{R_1^2 + r_{cm}^2} = 2.02759 \cdot 10^{10} m$). Having found these values I can now plug them in Newton's law of uniform gravitation $F = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$ with G being the gravitational constant, M being the sum of the masses of planet 1 and 2, m being the mass of planet 3 and r being the distance from the center of mass to planet 3. Plugging these values gives me $F = 4.87 \cdot 10^8 N$.

But the problem I'm having is that I get a different value if I were to calculate the froces from planet 1 and planet 2 separately (which is also how the model answer does it).

Calculating the forces separately:
$\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}$

$\vec{F}_{1,3} = 3.335 \cdot 10^8 N \uvec{i}$ (just plugging the values in Newton's law of uniform gravitation). Calculating the magintude of $\vec{F}_{2, 3}$: $F_{2, 3} = 1.334 \cdot 10^8 N$ with $r = \sqrt{R_1^2 + R_2^2}$ the distance from $m_2$ to $m_3$. In order to write this as a vector, I need to find the angle $\theta$ first, $\theta = \arctan{\frac{10^{10}m}{2 \cdot 10^{10}m}} = 26.565º$. This gives $\vec{F}_{2, 3} = F_{2, 3} \cdot \cos({\arctan{0.5}}) \uvec{i} + F_{2, 3} \cdot \sin({\arctan{0.5}}) \uvec{j}$ which is roughly equal to $\vec{F}_{2, 3} = 1.193 \cdot 10^8 N \uvec{i} + 0.5966 \cdot 10^8 N \uvec{j}$. Now calculating the magnitude of the total force gives $F = \sqrt{(3.335 \cdot 10^8 N + 1.193 \cdot 10^8)^2 + (0.5966 \cdot 10^8)^2} = 4.57 \cdot 10^8 N$.

Also if I calculate the angle between the force and the x-axis (suppose that $R_1$ lies on the x-axis) I also get different values for the different cases.

Now my question is, why are these values (both force and angle) different? Shouldn't they be the same since the gravitational force points towards the center of mass or is my way of thinking flawed?

(Disclaimer: it is very possible that I made a dumb mistake or made a rounding error, sorry if that would be the case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the gravitational force points towards the center of mass or is my way of thinking flawed?

That can be an erroneous assumption.  If the distribution of mass being analyzed is spherical, Newton's gravitational force works out to "point towards the center of mass." So, for each of your planets you can analyze them as being point masses. Your $M_1$ and $M_2$ planets do **not** form a spherical distribution of mass, so the assumption will fail, as your math shows.

When we analyze small masses on Earth we are dealing with small volumes, and more importantly, we are assuming a constant gravitational field across the object. That makes the assumption of gravity acting through the center of mass acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

X(com) = M1X1 + M2X2 + ........
by differentiating both sides with respect to time gives
A(com) = M1A1 + M2A2 + M3A3........         ( where X is position vecor and A is accleration vector)

but GM1M3(X1-X3)/|x1-x3|^3 + GM2M3(X2 - X3)/ | x2- x3|^3 is not equal to G(M1 + M2)M3(X(com of M1 and M2) - X3)/|xcom - x3|^3